# Import revised Z coordinate data into an Object

Tags: scripting, export, vertices, import

I exported the vertex coordinates (x,y,z) of an object in a csv file.  I adjusted the Z coordinates in EXCEL, for the purpose of smoothing (a road).
I now want to import the adjusted Z-coordinates into the mesh/object, i.e. the reverse of when I exported the coordinates.  I did the export using a python script I found here.  Is there a way (script) to import x,y,z into an existing object?  I don't want to do it manually!

Comment: If you have excel output the coordinates in a csv file you should be able to read the csv file into an array and use it to adjust the points.  If you assume that the index of the coordinates haven't changed this should be an easy script.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of many ways this could be done.

### What to Do

This will only work if you've done nothing in Blender to change the order or number of vertex coordinates and assumes that you didn't write the coordinate index into the original CSV file.

Export your coordinates from Excel as a CSV file.  Export them as 'x, y, z' using comma as the separator.

Select the road object.

Run this script, setting `csvFilename` to the name of the CSV file

```py
import bpy
import csv

csvFilename = "YOUR_FILE_NAME_HERE"

import bmesh
object = bpy.context.active_object
assert(object.type == "MESH")
if not object.mode == 'EDIT':
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(object.data)
else:
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(object.data)

verts = bm.verts
verts.ensure_lookup_table()

with open(csvFilename, 'r') as csvFile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', 
        quotechar='|',
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    index = 0
    for row in csvreader:
        verts[index].co.z = row[2]
        index += 1

if not object.mode == 'EDIT':
    bm.to_mesh(object.data)
    bm.free()
else:
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(object.data)
```

If you don't use comma as a delimiter, you should change the `delimiter=','` argument to whatever you do use.

If you export the data in a different format, change the 2 in `row[2]` to the Z position in the row, counting the first element as position 0.

### How It Works

This uses Python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library to read your file.  Setting `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONUMERIC` as an argument to the reader causes the reader to convert each element to a float, unless it is quoted.

The reader returns one row at a time, in a Python array, with one value per array position.

Comment: My adjusted coordinates (x,y,z) are in an Excel workbook.

Comment: Excel has the ability to export to a CSV file.  I can't give you specifics, because it varies by version of Excel, but basically you select the coordinates and export to csv.

Comment: sorry.  missed my edit window

Comment: What is the proper CSV format and how does one create that in Excel?  Is it simply the same format as I exported from Blender, i.e. the x y and z coordinates for each vertex in one row separated by commas and a space?

Where should CSV file be when I run the script?  I assume I run script with blender object in EDIT mode and w/ ALL selected?

Comment: You want the file to have one row per vertex, with x y and z separated by commas.  In other words it should look just like the file you copied from.  You change the `csvFilename` from YOUR_FILE_NAME_HERE to where you had Excel write the CSV file.  You can run it in either EDIT or OBJECT mode and the selection doesn't matter.  It assumes it will change every vertex.

Comment: where do I save the CSV file?  I am running the script from Blender with the object in question "open", and the python script in the "scripting" tab, but not clear to me where csv file is supposed to be such that the script execution can access the csv.
b.t.w, you are very helpful.

Comment: In Excel, when you write the CSV file, it asks you where to put it.  Put it anywhere you like.  On Windows systems I use C:\tmp\file.csv for example. If you put it there, then change the csvfilename line to `csvFilename = r"C:\tmp\file.csv"`    You can use any file you want though.

Comment: My blender file is Z-up.
when I exported the vertex data from blender it was arrayed as X, Z, Y, so my CSV file (adjusted z coordinate) is arrayed as X, Z, Y.
I can get script to work (modify the z coordinate) when line 24 is: verts[index].co.z = row[2].  This seems to 
suggest that the first column is not being counted as zero but rather as "1"?  So, it's working, but I want to understand
why I'm having to work-around your fantastic instructions!

Comment: You're not working around them, they just weren't clear.  the '2' is for X, Y, Z, because Python counts from 0, so X is 0, Y is 1 and Z is 2 _if_ the numbers are in that order.  But yours are in the order X, Z, Y, so X is 0, but Z is 1 and Y is 2.  That's what I tried to say in the sentence "If you export the data in a different format, change the 2 in row[2] to the Z position in the row, counting the first element as position 0."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133512/discussion-between-g-lap-and-marty-fouts).